# c++ 15.4.0 wizard issue (templates)

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2017, wizard

In VS 15.4.0 they took out the template wizard, the one were you can choose dynamic link library, empty project, console app, etc. They took that out and now I am wondering how to make an empty dynamic link library / no compiled header or `#include <stdfx.h>`.

Comment: Improved spelling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select Windows Desktop Wizard when creating a new project.